# Start/stop instances across multiple cloud providers

Tags: terraform

Assuming a cloud infrastructure across multiple cloud provider accounts (AWS, Azure and GC) built with Terraform. Is there any way to reboot instances using Terraform? If not, how do people easily and centrally reboot their instances created with Terraform?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to reboot the instances? Is it a specific instance, a group of them or all of them?

Comment: I need the ability to reboot specific instances in a case where my service (or OS) is stuck

Answer (score 1):

Terraform does not provide capacity to reboot your instances. At best, you could taint a resource, that means that terraform will destroy and recreate (which is obviously not the same the rebooting). Terraform is not the right tool to manage the lifecycle of your instance.

Usually, the best practice is to get your instance automatically rebooted, using cloudwatch on AWS. You need to configure it to detect unhealthy instances. I guess other cloud providers have a similar feature.

If you need to do it manually, next step would be to use the cloud API (such as aws cli) to perform this action. I am not aware of a tool that let you do that across cloud providers centrally.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into using Ansible to perform the reboots. They appear to have wide cloud provider coverage